# How to limit a button's size when it has an image?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying out buttons in Tk, and I've loaded up an image to a button:

```
package require Tk

image create photo myimage -file "../button.png"
ttk::button .button -image myimage

place .button -x 0 -y 0
```

However the `button.png` image is very large (200x100), so the button resizes itself to show the entire image. Is it possible to resize the button to a specific size, e.g. 100x50 (maybe by using the grid layout?), and have the button resample its image so it fits within the button?

Answer (score 0):

Tk's button classes (`button` and `ttk::button`) handle images by resizing themselves to contain the content exactly. They never automatically resample (and that's a bit tricky to get right in general, as the right way to do it depends on the details of the content of the image) the images; you have to do that yourself.

```
image create photo myimage -file "../button.png"
set subsampled [image create photo]
$subsampled copy myimage -subsample 2 2
ttk::button .button -image $subsampled

place .button -x 0 -y 0
```

Tk's built in subsampling code isn't very good! If you know what you're doing with image processing (well, more than me!) then you could probably use [CRIMP](http://chiselapp.com/user/andreas_kupries/repository/crimp/doc/tip/embedded/www/doc/files/crimp.html) to do something much better. But I just look at the documentation for `crimp decimate xy` — which appears to be the right thing — and scratch my head.